# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'postmetas'

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

**Post Modle**

```
public function postmeta(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Postmeta::class,'postmetas', 'post_id','value');
}
```

**postmetas**

```
       Schema::create('postmetas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('post_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('value');
    });
    Schema::table('postmetas', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');

    });
```

**blade file**

```
   @foreach($post->postmeta as $watch_link)
                                    
    @endforeach
```

when I trying to edit get that error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'postmetas' (SQL: select `postmetas`.*, `postmetas`.`post_id` as `pivot_post_id`, `postmetas`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `postmetas` inner join `postmetas` on `postmetas`.`id` = `postmetas`.`value` where `postmetas`.`post_id` = 2) (View: C:\laragon\www\anime-laravel\resources\views\backend\post\update.blade.php)
```

Answer (score 0):

In many to many relation, there should be a third table called pivot table, in which your data is stored.

**Post Model**

```
public function postmetas(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Postmeta::class,'post_postmeta', 'post_id','postmeta_id');
}
```

**Postmeta Model**

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class,'post_postmeta', 'postmeta_id','post_id');
}
```

**Posts table migration**

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->id();
   $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Postmetas table migration**

```
Schema::create('postmetas', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('value');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Post-postmeta table migration**

```
Schema::create('post-postmeta', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('post_id');
    $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('postmeta_id');
    $table->foreign('postmeta_id')->references('id')->on('postmetas');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Foreach loop

```
@foreach($post->postmetas as $watch_link)
   {{$watch_link->pivot->value}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: i done what u said but i get that error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'post_postmetas' (SQL: select `post_postmetas`.*, `post_postmetas`.`post_id` as `pivot_post_id`, `post_postmetas`.`postmeta_id` as `pivot_postmeta_id` from `post_postmetas` inner join `post_postmetas` on `post_postmetas`.`id` = `post_postmetas`.`postmeta_id` where `post_postmetas`.`post_id` = 3) (View: C:\laragon\www\anime-